# Replacing a Plone content item without breaking link integrity

Tags: plone

In a Plone site I have a page that I want to replace with a folder. However, this page has a number of incoming links from elsewhere in the site. Since I'm using the link-by-UID feature, these links will break if I force the deletion of the page so that I can create the folder in its place.

What is the best way to turn the page into a folder and keep all the incoming links working?

Comment: Create a custom method which allows you to "fix" page UID after the old object and UID have been forcefully deleted having link integrity disabled? Fix being = set UID the same as old UID.

Comment: Manually fiddling with the UIDs is asking for trouble. (At the very least, there's a couple race conditions because some other new object might get that UID in the meantime, somebody might already rely on the new UID of the folder, etc.. Might be slightly safer to keep the page, create the folder, then swap the UIDs then delete the page.)

Comment: The Plone UID is a random 128bit value, so creating one content item per second there's no danger of finding a collision until well after all the stars in the universe have burnt themselves out ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Products.contentmigration](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.contentmigration) with a [CustomQueryWalker](https://github.com/plone/Products.contentmigration/blob/master/Products/contentmigration/walker.py#L11) (though you will have to temporarly disable the link integrity check but it works).